# Composite API request calling after insert twice for same root

Tags: trigger, rest-api, composite

I am firing a composite request.
And I can see there are two debug logs getting generated with different Payment__c id.

```
StudentPaymentTrigger on Student_Payment trigger event AfterInsert|__sfdc_trigger/StudentPaymentTrigger

08:54:02.0 (10954264)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[6]|studentPayment|{"Student__c":"0015i000003bGwfAAE","LastModifiedDate":"2021-09-23T03:24:01.000Z","IsDeleted":false,"CreatedById":"0055i000000YNXqAAO","CreatedDate":"2021-09-23T03:24:01.000Z","Payment__c":"a0e5i000001B826AAC","Id":"a0g5i0000019t9EAAQ","LastModifiedById":"0055i000000YNXqAAO","Name":"SP-4250669","SystemModstamp":"2021-09-23T03:24:01.000Z"}|0xe2cbeab
```

And second one is :

```
StudentPaymentTrigger on Student_Payment trigger event AfterInsert|__sfdc_trigger/StudentPaymentTrigger

08:54:03.0 (5927772)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[6]|studentPayment|{"Student__c":"0015i000003bGwfAAE","LastModifiedDate":"2021-09-23T03:24:03.000Z","IsDeleted":false,"CreatedById":"0055i000000YNXqAAO","CreatedDate":"2021-09-23T03:24:03.000Z","Payment__c":"a0e5i000001B827AAC","Id":"a0g5i0000019t9FAAQ","LastModifiedById":"0055i000000YNXqAAO","Name":"SP-4250670","SystemModstamp":"2021-09-23T03:24:03.000Z"}|0x2caec5e2
```

Why the trigger getting fired twice when the composite request is only getting triggered once. Is this expected behaviour?

Composite Request:

```
{
    "allOrNone": true,
    "compositeRequest": [
        {
            "method": "PATCH",
            "url": "/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Account/Premium_ID__c/76767676985",
            "referenceId": "RefStudent76767676985",
            "body": {
                "FirstName": "Dummy Sachin353454354311111010",
                "LastName": "Kumar353454354311111010",
                "Super_Status__c": "PE/First60",
                "Status__c": "New",
                "Sub_Status__c": "",
                "Current_Class__c": "9",
                "BillingState": "Karnataka (KA)",
                "Expiry_date__c": "2022-06-09",
                "Manager__c": "",
                "Lead_Category__c": "Non-EMI",
                "Type_Of_Student__c": "",
                "Student_Type__c": "",
                "Parent_Name__c": "Yugraj Singh",
                "PersonEmail": "dinesh.rajamani@***s.com",
                "Phone": "9739795926",
                "Student_Email_ID__c":"std@std.com",
                "Student_Phone_Number__c": "8428575275",
                "Alternate_Number_1__c": "8428575275",
                "Alternate_Number_2__c": "8428575275",
                "Alternate_Number_3__c": "8428575275",
                "Created_On__c": "2020-07-03",
                "BillingStreet": "133",
                "BillingCountry": "India",
                "BillingCity": "",
                "BillingPostalCode": "",
                "ShippingStreet": "2212 18th main road",
                "ShippingState": "Karnataka",
                "ShippingCountry": "India",
                "ShippingCity": "Bangalore",
                "ShippingPostalCode": "560008",
                "Parent_App_Code__c": "BS-1234",
                "Session_1_Date__c": "2020-06-21",
                "Shipped_Activity_Date__c": "2020-05-21",
                "Order_Punched_By__c": "*** Admin",
                "E_Score__c": "",
                "Version__c": "V1.2.1",
                "High_Priority_PE_Date__c": "2020-05-14",
                "Date_of_Birth__c": "1995-09-07",
                "Last_online_time__c": "12:20 am",
                "Back_End_Dashboard__c": "https://www.***.com/resources/dashboard-examples",
                "WhatsApp_OPTOUT__c": true,
                "Creation_Agent__c": "Test Agent 11",
                "Transfer_type__c": "",
                "Notes__c": "24 test note",
                "BHLP_BOCP__c": "",
                "BHLP_BOCP_Day_1__c": "Monday",
                "BHLP_BOCP_Time_1__c":"18:45:00",
                "BHLP_BOCP_Day_2__c": "Tuesday",
                "BHLP_BOCP_Time_2__c":"18:45:00",
                "BHLP_BOCP_Day_3__c": "Wednesday",
                "BHLP_BOCP_Time_3__c":"18:45:00",
                "BHLP_BOCP_Day_4__c": "Thursday",
                "BHLP_BOCP_Time_4__c":"18:45:00",
                "BHLP_BOCP_Day_5__c": "Friday",
                "BHLP_BOCP_Time_5__c":"18:45:00",
                "BHLP_BOCP_Day_6__c": "Saturday",
                "BHLP_BOCP_Time_6__c":"18:45:00",
                "BHLP_BOCP_Day_7__c": "Sunday",
                "BHLP_BOCP_Time_7__c":"18:45:00",
                "BHLP_BOCP_Start_Date__c": "2020-08-07"
            }
        },
        {
            "method": "PATCH",
            "url": "/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Order__c/Order_No__c/ORD76767676985",
            "referenceId": "RefORD76767676985",
            "body": {
                "Name": "Order : Student76767676985",
                "Course_Name__c": "9th Physics",
                "Order_Start_Date__c": "2020-05-11",
                "Board__c": "ICSE",
                "Order_Product_name__c": "Product 1;Product 2;Product 3",
                "Books__c": "Book 1;Book 2",
                "Active_AWB_Number__c": "AWB-1236",
                "Active_Order_Delivery_Date__c": "2020-08-17",
                "K3_Validity_End_Date__c": "2020-06-19",
                "Active_Order_Value__c": "45000",
                "Status__c": "Confirmed",
                "Active_Order_Shipped_Date__c": "2020-06-19",
                "K12_Validity_End_Date__c": "2020-06-19",
                "Order_type__c" : "Fresh order",
                "FOC_Bypass__c" : false
            }
        },
        {
            "method": "POST",
            "url": "/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Student_Orders__c",
            "referenceId": "STUORD76767676985",
            "body": {
                "Name": "Student Order : Sat Demo353454354311111010000",
                "Order__c": "@{RefORD76767676985.id}",
                "Student__c": "@{RefStudent76767676985.id}"
            }
        },
        {
            "method": "PATCH",
            "url": "/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Payment__c/Payment_Reference_ID__c/PD76767676985",
            "referenceId": "RefPaymentPD76767676985",
            "body": {
                "Payment_Amount__c": "100",
                "Payment_Type__c": "Non-EMI",
                "Payment_Category__c": "Full payment",
                "Payment_Method__c": "",
                "Payment_Date__c": "2020-05-21",
                "Tenurity__c": "",
                "Estimated_Monthly_EMI__c": "",
                "Loan_Reference_Id__c": "",
                "Order__r": {
                    "Order_No__c": "ORD76767676985"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "method": "POST",
            "url": "/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Student_Payment__c",
            "referenceId": "STUPAY76767676985",
            "body": {
                "Payment__c": "@{RefPaymentPD76767676985.id}",
                "Student__c": "@{RefStudent76767676985.id}"
            }
        },
        {
            "method": "PATCH",
            "url": "/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Order__c/Order_No__c/ORD176767676985",
            "referenceId": "RefORD176767676985",
            "body": {
                "Name": "Order : Student176767676985",
                "Course_Name__c": "9th Physics",
                "Order_Start_Date__c": "2020-05-11",
                "Board__c": "ICSE",
                "Order_Product_name__c": "Product 1;Product 2;Product 3",
                "Books__c": "Book 1;Book 2",
                "Active_AWB_Number__c": "AWB-1236",
                "Active_Order_Delivery_Date__c": "2020-08-17",
                "K3_Validity_End_Date__c": "2020-06-19",
                "Active_Order_Value__c": "45000",
                "Status__c": "Confirmed",
                "Active_Order_Shipped_Date__c": "2020-06-19",
                "K12_Validity_End_Date__c": "2020-06-19",
                "Order_type__c" : "Fresh order",
                "FOC_Bypass__c" : false
            }
        },
        {
            "method": "POST",
            "url": "/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Student_Orders__c",
            "referenceId": "STUORD176767676985",
            "body": {
                "Name": "Student Order : Sat Demo353454354311111010000",
                "Order__c": "@{RefORD176767676985.id}",
                "Student__c": "@{RefStudent76767676985.id}"
            }
        },
        {
            "method": "PATCH",
            "url": "/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Payment__c/Payment_Reference_ID__c/PD176767676985",
            "referenceId": "RefPaymentPD176767676985",
            "body": {
                "Payment_Amount__c": "100",
                "Payment_Type__c": "Non-EMI",
                "Payment_Category__c": "Full payment",
                "Payment_Method__c": "",
                "Payment_Date__c": "2020-05-21",
                "Tenurity__c": "",
                "Estimated_Monthly_EMI__c": "",
                "Loan_Reference_Id__c": "",
                "Order__r": {
                    "Order_No__c": "ORD176767676985"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "method": "POST",
            "url": "/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Student_Payment__c",
            "referenceId": "STUPAY176767676985",
            "body": {
                "Payment__c": "@{RefPaymentPD176767676985.id}",
                "Student__c": "@{RefStudent76767676985.id}"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If you see `Student_Payment__c `, but trigger should run only once for after insert context and have two `Student_Payment__c ` records . In my case trigger gets called twice each having single `Student_Payment__c ` id.

Comment: Each request in a composite is a separate call. You have two POST requests to `/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Student_Payment__c` with different ref ids

Comment: Yes, but the triggers should be called in bulkified way, right? Or if I push 5 post requests via composite api, my triggers will get called 5 times?

Comment: They'll get called 5 times, there's no optimization of the sort you're envisioning in a composite request

Answer (score 0):

As identigral mentioned, each will be a separate request. The [Composite REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_composite.htm)

> **Executes a series of REST API requests** in a single call. You can use
> the output of one request as the input to a subsequent request. The
> response bodies and HTTP statuses of the requests are returned in a
> single response body. The entire series of requests counts as a single
> call toward your API limits.

So, even though it's only using one call - it's executing the sub-requests separately.

Your use case, bulkified creation of multiple records for an object, is better covered in [Create Multiple Records](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_composite_sobject_tree_flat.htm) with using [sObject Tree](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobject_tree.htm)

> While the sObject Tree resource can be used to create nested records,
> **you can also create multiple, unrelated records of the same type. In a
> single request, you can create up to two hundred records.**

`https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v53.0/composite/tree/Account`

```
{
"records" :[{
    "attributes" : {"type" : "Account", "referenceId" : "ref1"},
    "name" : "SampleAccount1",
    "phone" : "1111111111",
    "website" : "www.salesforce.com",
    "numberOfEmployees" : "100",
    "industry" : "Banking"   
    },{
    "attributes" : {"type" : "Account", "referenceId" : "ref2"},
    "name" : "SampleAccount2",
    "phone" : "2222222222",
    "website" : "www.salesforce2.com",
    "numberOfEmployees" : "250",
    "industry" : "Banking"
    },
...
}
```